Prisma Supabase, NuxtJs
`[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500]
Invalid prisma.videos.findMany() invocation in
C:...\server\api\get-videos.ts:10:1
7 const offset = query.offset ? parseInt(query.offset as string) : 0
8 const limit = query.limit ? parseInt(query.limit as string) : 10
9
→ 10 const videos = await prisma.videos.findMany(
Can't reach database server at aws-0-eu-central-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at aws-0-eu-central-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432.
Can't reach database server at aws-0-eu-central-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432`
//
After I make many requests it gives me this error, and subsequent requests also have errors. On the local server everything works fine, connections to the database are the same
DB_URL=postgresql://postgres.cnftqjluuyftofvirwbb:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@aws-0-eu-central-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres
host netlify
npx prisma generate && npm run build
tried to connect with ?pgbouncer=true, ?connection_timeout=10&query_timeout=3000
